# Modifying admin post list buttons/dropdown

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've created my own custom post type search filter and instead of having another menu i want to append the select options to the default woocommerce status filter dropdown select.

[image]

Also i want to change both the `Filter` and `Search Orders` buttons text to `Go`.

Here is how i add my own dropdown select but instead i want to append.

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );


function wpse45436_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts(){
    $type = 'shop_order';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }

    //only add filter to post type you want
    if ('shop_order' == $type){
        //change this to the list of values you want to show
        //in 'label' => 'value' format
        $values = array(
            'Ordered From Supplier' => 'ordered_supplier', 
            'Ready for Dispatch' => 'ready_dispatched',
            'Despatched' => 'despatched',
            'Delivered' => 'delivered',
            'Returns' => 'returns',
        );
        ?>
        <select name="shop_order_status_2" class="chzn-done">
        <option value="" selected><?php _e('Show All Order Statuses ', 'wose45436'); ?></option>

        <?php
            $current_v = isset($_GET['shop_order_status_2'])? $_GET['shop_order_status_2']:'';
            foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
                printf
                    (
                        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                        $value,
                        $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
                        $label
                    );
                }
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}
```

How do i accomplish this?  What filters do i use?

Comment: What version are you using? Granted I am using the bleeding edge code from github, but I am not seeing an Order Status filter at all, but rather the statuses are links above the filters. All (3) | On hold (2) | Completed (1)

Comment: I'm using woocommerce 2.3.7

Comment: Ok, I checked my live site which is using that version of WC and am not seeing them there either. http://tinyurl.com/mpf5vue. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-post-types.php#L1609) that only filter added by WC core is the customer search input. Could that be coming from anywhere else?

Comment: Ok, might be a possibility an old developer added some javascript.  Do you know how to change the button text?

Comment: There's no filter in `submit_button()` so you will either have to use javascript or perhaps filter the `gettext()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can change the button text by filtering the [`gettext()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext). This is what allows the button text to be translated, but it can also be hijacked for this type of purpose.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'so_29631694_modify_filter_button_text' );

function so_29631694_modify_filter_button_text( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ){
    if( is_admin() && 'Filter' == $untranslated_text){
        $translated_text = 'Go';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Or you could do it with a little jQuery:

```
$('order-query-submit').attr('value', 'Go');
```